# bash print x number of files before file found using ls

Tags: bash, ls

I have a directory which has a bunch of files that are in yyyymmdd.hhmmss format. I am looking for the x number of files before a certain time is inquired.

For example, I have a directory with files that are named every 2 minutes (e.g., 20190205.000200, 20190205.000400, 20190205.000600, ... , 20190205.235800). I want the name of x files before a time is entered. For an example, let's say I choose the time to be '20190205.200000', and I want 15 files. This would produce the files from 20190205.193000 to 20190205.20000 (15 files at 2-min timestep = half hour). Is there a way for the 'ls' command to do this (perhaps even with awk, grep, sed, etc.)? Or would it be easier to convert to a datetime and loop through every 2 minutes?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could list the content of the directory, grep the name of the file and display `X` entry before the match

With these files

```
  ls -1   
20190205.0000000
20190205.0000200
20190205.0000400
20190205.0000600
20190205.0000800
20190205.0001000
20190205.0001200
20190205.0001400
20190205.0001600
20190205.0001800
20190205.0002000
```

You could do

```
  ls -1 | grep 20190205.0001400 -B 3 
20190205.0000800
20190205.0001000
20190205.0001200
20190205.0001400
```

Where the `-B` flag it used to set the number of lines to show before the match